# Add a key value in json file using java

Tags: java, json

I have a json file which look like as below.

```
 {
  "List": [
    {
      "C1": "A",
      "C2": "mail1",
      "C3": "1"
    },
    {
      "C1": "B",
      "C2": "mail2",
      "C3": "2"
    },
    {
      "C1": "C",
      "C2": "mail3",
      "C3": "3"
    },
    {
      "C1": "D",
      "C2": "mail4",
      "C3": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

I wanted to add a key value to this json file.It should look like this.

```
  {
      "List": [
        {
          "C0": "I1",
          "C1": "A",
          "C2": "mail1",
          "C3": "1"
        },
        {
          "C0": "I2",
          "C1": "B",
          "C2": "mail2",
          "C3": "2"
        },
        {
          "C0": "I3",
          "C1": "C",
          "C2": "mail3",
          "C3": "3"
        },
        {
          "C0": "I4",
          "C1": "D",
          "C2": "mail4",
          "C3": "4"
        }
      ]
}
```

How can we achieve this in java8.I have tried with the jackson-all-1.9.0 jar
but it is adding key value at last.Help is appriciated.

Comment: you cannot change the order in an existing map. It preserves the insertion order. One thing you can try out is by, creating a new map by putting the new key value pair and then put all the key values from the original map to the newly created map

Comment: Show us the code with which you tried to do it with jackson. It's hard to help you fix the code we can't see

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in the following way.

```
try {

        JSONObject objs = new JSONObject("{\"List\":[\n" +
                "{\"C1\":\"A\",\"C2\":\"mail1\",\"C3\":\"1\"},\n" +
                "{\"C1\":\"B\",\"C2\":\"mail2\",\"C3\":\"2\"},\n" +
                "{\"C1\":\"C\",\"C2\":\"mail3\",\"C3\":\"3\"},\n" +
                "{\"C1\":\"D\",\"C2\":\"mail4\",\"C3\":\"4\"}\n" +
                "]}");

        JSONArray jsonArray=objs.getJSONArray("List");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            obj.put("C0", "I" + (i + 1));
            jsonArray.put(i,obj);
        }
        Log.v("TAG_RESULT",jsonArray.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you compiled this code, this is not a JSONArray.

Comment: @SachinGupta Then what it is?

Comment: It is a JsonObject

Comment: Have u seen the Code properly?

Comment: Getting The JSONObject from JSONArray and then adding the key and Updating the JSONArray

Comment: First line will throw exception saying : A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Comment: Now, yes it is.

Comment: @Chandankushwaha I see the code which is perfect, But I just want to know what does it mean? actually, I don't know.    *** Log.v

Comment: @pavan I just wanted to print the result. You can ignore it.

Comment: @Chandankushwaha got it. Thanks

Comment: @Chandankushwaha Its showing me issue :org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1] . Using code :JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("C:/Users/A.json"); to read json and rest of the code is same.

Comment: Can you please suggest ?

Comment: @user1734980 I have updated the Answer. Please check it.